# python tkinter using multiprocessing or multithreading and the program got frozen

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to make a GUI program using tkinter that also enables executing another program at the same time

so it is important not to make any of the programs get stuck or frozen

so i used multiprocessing and threading module

however, i got a problem

the problem is that among the two processes, the second process(which is a file dialog to execute external program) does not start until the first process ends which is the GUI program.

the code flow looks as follow

thank you

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox
import io, hashlib, queue, sys, time, threading, traceback
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import threading
import multiprocessing

class Layout(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=200, height=750, background="white")
        self.xsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.ysb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))

        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.canvas.fontSize = 12

        # This is what enables using the mouse:
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.move_start)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_move)
        #linux scroll
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-4>", self.zoomerP)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-5>", self.zoomerM)
        #windows scroll
        self.canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)

    #move
    def move_start(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
    def move_move(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    #windows zoom
    def zoomer(self, event):
        if (event.delta > 0):
            self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
            self.canvas.fontSize = self.canvas.fontSize * 1.1
        elif (event.delta < 0):
            self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
            self.canvas.fontSize = self.canvas.fontSize * 0.9
        for child_widget in self.canvas.find_withtag("text"):
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(child_widget, font = ("Helvetica", int(self.canvas.fontSize)))
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    #linux zoom
    def zoomerP(self, event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
        self.canvas.fontSize = self.canvas.fontSize * 1.1
        for child_widget in self.canvas.find_withtag("text"):
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(child_widget, font = ("Helvetica", int(self.canvas.fontSize)))
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    def zoomerM(self,event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.canvas.fontSize = self.canvas.fontSize * 0.9
        for child_widget in self.canvas.find_withtag("text"):
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(child_widget, font = ("Helvetica", int(self.canvas.fontSize)))
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))


class main_window():

        root = Tk()

        root.title("Seoul Cell")
        root.geometry("1300x1000")
        root.resizable(True, True)

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            
            global monitor1
            monitor1 = Layout(root)
            monitor1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # 메뉴바 생성
        menu = Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=menu)

        menu_file = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu_file.add_command(label="Open Cell Information")
        menu_file.add_command(label="Partitioning")
        menu_file.add_command(label="Pairing")
        menu_file.add_command(label="Placement")
        menu_file.add_command(label="Routing")
        menu.add_cascade(label="Task", menu = menu_file )


        menu_work = Menu(menu, tearoff= 0)
        menu_work.add_command(label="Open layerinfo file")
        menu_work.add_command(label="save as layerinfo.txt")
        menu.add_cascade(label="TechInfo", menu = menu_work)


        # 2번째 메뉴바

        menu2_frame = Frame(root)
        menu2_frame.pack(fill = "x")
        layer_but = Button(menu2_frame, text = "Layers")
        layer_but.pack(side = "left", padx=3, pady=3)

        # Script

        script_frame = LabelFrame(root, text = "script")
        script_frame.pack(fill='x', side="bottom",padx=10, pady=10)

        script_menu_frame = Frame(script_frame)
        script_menu_frame.pack(fill='x')


        # Script Text box

        scrollbar_script = Scrollbar(script_frame)
        scrollbar_script.pack(side='right',fill="y")

        script = Text(script_frame, height=20, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_script.set)
        script.pack(fill='x', side="bottom", padx=10, pady=10)
        scrollbar_script.config(command=script.yview)
        
    
        root.mainloop()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target= main_window).start()
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target= os.system(f"{filedialog.askopenfilename(title = 'Choose the execution File')}")).start()
```

Comment: First I think `main_window()` should be a function instead of a class definition.  Second you assign the result of `os.system(...)` to `target` option in the second `Process(...)` which is not a callable object.

Comment: Also you need to put the last two lines inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.  You don't need to execute `main_window()` in another process, just execute it in current process.